# JRadiobutton selection not showing

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jradiobutton

Java: I have a 3 `JRadioButtons` added to a `JPanel`, which is added to a GraphicsProgram. When I Run the program, I can select the radiobuttons (when I click the buttons, they do function). However, the `JPanel` doesn't show the new selection. In other words, even though the selections WORK, they don't show.

Even when I add the radio buttons to a `ButtonGroup`, it doesn't work. I tried repaint() for the JPanel toolbar, but it still doesn't work.

A link to a screenshot of the applet while it is running. The Radio buttons are stuck that way. When I  click "Pellets" or "Gate", it still shows that "Walls" is selected. However, even though the buttons don't SHOW the correct selection, they still ARE selected.

[image]

```
toolbar = new JPanel();

wallButton = new JRadioButton("Walls");
wallButton.setActionCommand("walls");
wallButton.setSelected(true);

pelletButton = new JRadioButton("Pellets");
pelletButton.setActionCommand("pellets");

gateButton = new JRadioButton("Gate");
gateButton.setActionCommand("gate");

toolbar.add(wallButton);
toolbar.add(pelletButton);
toolbar.add(gateButton);

wallButton.addActionListener(this);
pelletButton.addActionListener(this);
gateButton.addActionListener(this);

add(toolbar, SOUTH);
```

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't show"? The radio buttons don't paint/show the selection or that the result of the change doesn't show (ie what you're doing in your ActionListener)?

Comment: Can you post a short, compilable example ([SSCCE](http://sscce.org)), duplicating this issue, so we can test it out?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing `ButtonGroup`

Add the following code before `add()`:

```
ButtonGroup radioButtonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
radioButtonGroup.add(wallButton);
radioButtonGroup.add(pelletButton);
radioButtonGroup.add(gateButton);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! I tried it but I'm afraid it still does not work. I added a paragraph for two things I have tried but don't work. I also added a screenshot of the applet while it is running.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a layouting issue of your `JRadioButton`s on your `toolbar` panel. Try setting a `LayoutManager` (May be a `new FlowLayout()`) to the `toolBar` panel.

Answer (score 0):

You MUST call `repaint()` and `revalidate()` after a component is changed. Try to add these methods on your `RadioButton`s' action listeners.